# String comparison is failing in Salesforce

Tags: string, salesforce, comparison-operators

We are having some weird issue while comparing two strings in apex class :

- We have a list of strings in which we store csv file headers after
  parsing that in salesforce.
- Then we compare each of these headers value in salesforce . In some
  situation we are getting same debug's for both string values but
  the check of STRING.EQUALSIGNORECASE is failing.
- I have assumed that the value in either of the string may contain some garbage or value of other type but not sure .
  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Although "EQUALSIGNORECASE" is not case sensitive, it is whitespace sensitive.  Try trimming your strings before comparing them.

```
.trim()
```